# Importing a survey from Limesurvey to Android app

Tags: android, view, limesurvey

I'm developing a native Android app in which I'll be using a survey created on Limesurvey. My current approach is to fetch the survey structure from Limesurvey server and then render survey on the android app, like creating a view/design of question in android app. The view will have be to generated at runtime depending upon the data fetch from Limesurvey Server.

My question is do you think that it's a realistic approach of rendering question views in android app at run?

and do you know if there is already a designated way of integrating limesurvey in android app?

Thanks

Comment: A question : why do an android App if you need a runtime system (then active conexion to internet) ? WHy not directly use a clean RWD ready template ?

Comment: By runtime I meant the app will generate surveys dynamically rather than static. The app also has to work in offline mode. I have one question from you Denis, can you tell me the API to call if I to want see the options of a multiple choice question? like, by using 'list_questions' I'm able to fetch all questions but the question with multiple choices to select, I can;t see those choices' texts.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run Limesurvey surveys using your Android device, all you need is a mobile optimized template (check http://www.limesurvey-templates.com/smartphone-tablet-optimized-c-28.html for some professional Limesurvey templates which are already optimized for mobile). Then you can use your device's browser to take the survey , assuming an Internet connection is available.

If you want to use a native Android app that also supports running Limesurvey surveys offline, have a look at "OfflineSurveys": http://www.offlinesurveys.com.

There is no need to re-invent the wheel!